# Angularjs http catch block response status is 0 from custom server

Tags: angularjs, http

To simulate and debug a failing HTTP request, I started a nodejs server that only returns 503, but in all the cases, the `status` property on failure object is 0, even though the network tab shows the correct statusCode and message.

Following is the angularjs code that makes the http call:

```js
$http.get( Url )
        .then( function( res ) {
            //regular code
            })
        .catch( function onFail ( reason ) {
            var errorMsg = "Error from server: " + reason.status + reason.statusText );
        })
        .finally( function onFinally() {
        });
```

Inspecting the `reason` object.
[image: failure object]

What could be the reason for the status being 0?

Comment: Your code has several syntax errors. Eg line 4 you have ; before the .catch, and before the .finally you have 2 stops (..). I'd also suggest you use instead of finally another .then().catch()

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, fixed the syntax errors.

Comment: Is the error now resolved?

Comment: No, the syntax errors were introduced by me removing the `bind` calls while creating the question. My code works, the error is still there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is the request was aborted. Probably you don't have connection with internet, or maybe for some reason your web aplication could't read your return status (like test bellow with status 'failed') or your server is not returning error.

In angular documentation they mention the status 0 "Also, status codes less than -1 are normalized to zero. -1 usually means the request was aborted, e.g. using a config.timeout"

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#get

You can set a custom message when you got status 0 or -1 for lost internet connection.

```
.catch(function(error){

                //status = HTTP code
                if(error.status == -1 || error.status == 0)
                    error.statusText = "Failed to connect to internet";

                var errorMessage = "Ocurred an connection error. Status: '" + error.status + "', message: '" + error.statusText + "'";

                return {
                    success: false,
                    message: errorMessage
                };
            });
```

You can validate your return in your browser as you can see in my test bellow.

Test with wrong url, you can notice below column status '404'
[image: Test with wrong url]

Test offline, you can notice below column status 'failed'
[image: Test offline]